Ask wireless data permission before using it
I've a react native app. When you install the app for the first time after the install it would just stay on splash screen and crash. After crashing it would ask for wireless data permission like the attached image. Now i want the popup to show on top of app and the app should resume once given the permission. Is there any way i can request this permission and show on top? I found this question but seeing there is no answer given i had to ask here if anyone can help with this


AFAIK this dialog only appears in China. There is no explicit permission request for network access in iOS. The permission prompt is shown implicitly when an app first tries to access the network. You need to ensure that your app functions correctly (or at least doesn't hang/crash) with no network and can retry network operations once th user has responded to this dialog.

I'm not in china and it still shows. It shows on other users as well who are not in china. Retry logic is there. Its just that the prompt won't show unless its closed or crashed. That is the issue. If there's any way of invoking it then rest of the things can be handled

I have never seen that dialog. Searching indicates that it is only shown in phones from the China market. There is no specific call you can make to trigger that permission dialog.

To resolve this, you can use the react-native-permissions library to request network access permission explicitly and prevent the app from crashing during the initial launch.
Install the 'react-native-permissions' library:
npm install react-native-permissions
cd ios
pod install

In the app, you can add a function to request the wireless data permission (network access) at launch:
import { request, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS } from 'react-native-permissions';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const requestWirelessDataPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await request(
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY // iOS-specific
        : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE // Android-specific
    );
    if (result === RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      // Permission granted, continue with app functionality
    } else {
      // Permission denied, handle accordingly
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Permission error:', error);
  }
};

You can call this function during the app's initialization, ensuring it happens before any network requests or splash screen logic:
useEffect(() => {
  requestWirelessDataPermission();
}, []);

After making these changes, the permission dialog appears on top of the app when it’s launched, and the app no longer crashes. Once the permission is granted or denied, the app continues to function as expected.

Apple docs say that APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY permission is for tracking user data and sharing it across apps and websites. It might give users wrong impression that their data is being sold or something. Apple might reject app release. Do you have any info about that?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency

I'm sorry but this seems GenAI generated content
